# Prevent users to download web-contents with url and network exceptions via GPO

Tags: windows-server-2003, internet, internet-explorer, content-filter

We have server 2003, AD domain. Our clients XP, and W7 with IE7 IE8 browsers.

We use two types of internet. Use the internet inside the company network, and use mobile-net at home, with the same machines. (typically laptops, pda..)

So..it is possible to prevent download some content when user inside in the company network?

```
- when borwsing a site, prevent to download images, flash animations, videos..etc
- prevent this content control with some URL exception
- allow full browsing when user is outside the company...
```

Thank you folks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to implement a web proxy in your company.  Typically you'd install some sort of web proxy softwate and disallow internet access without going through that proxy.  A good proxy software can remove certain elements based on many factors, support per-source or per-user exceptions, etc.

Some information here on what a Proxy is/does:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server